# How does the React Context API work under the hood?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, react-context

So far I can only find descriptions of how to *use* the Context API, but not how it *works*, especially how consumer components are triggered to re-render. Links to source code would be awesome!

Comment: [Have at it](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactContext.js)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts this seems to just show the objects that are defined that are used by the runtime (e.g. `$$typeof: REACT_CONTEXT_TYPE,`) to do stuff, but I don't really know much about how the runtime works. I was looking more for links to Fiber code + a brief explanation to help get me started digging